# Accesing combobox values from anywhere

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, global-variables

I have two comboboxes, and I can get the values from them just fine. The problem is, I'd like it so that when both of the boxes are at a specific value, something happens. But I can't access either box's value outside its own listener.

The listener for the boxes:

```
character_class.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val){
```

Maybe I'm missing something simple, as I've been working on this project all day with few breaks, but I can't access `new_val` from anywhere else other than right there after the listener. Attempting to make it public fails, as for some reason it's only allowing `final` as a modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both of the changelisteners, simply get the value of the other `ComboBox` and check if it matches the specific values by calling `combobox.getValue()`

```
    ComboBox<String> c1 = new ComboBox<String>();
    c1.getItems().addAll("red", "blue", "green");

    ComboBox<String> c2 = new ComboBox<String>();
    c2.getItems().addAll("yellow", "purple", "blue");

    c1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
            String val = (String) newValue;
            if(val.equals(c2.getValue())){
                System.out.println("IT'S SAME");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Keep trying");
            }
        }
    });
```

And vice versa for the other combobox.

Comment: Doing this on the lower one works, as the above combobox has been declared, but trying to reference the lower combobox in the upper one gives an error that it can't be resolved.

Comment: Then add the changelistener after everything has been declared and show your code. Really got nothing to work with, with all you've posted.

Comment: Wow, okay, like I said, I'd been working on this all day with like 2 breaks....It wasn't clicking that the listeners didn't have to be right under their specific comboboxes...as usual, it's something simple staring me in the face that I just miss. Thanks man.